# is my javascript switch statement invalid?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to create click event on several DOMs. and when clicking each elements, it should append respective htmls. therefore, I tried to use switch statement.

```
<a href="#" data-index= 0 class="skill_item">skill</a>
<a href="#" data-index= 1 class="skill_item">skill</a>
```

I added data-index to distinguish DOM.

```
  $('#skill_item').click(function(event){

switch ($('this').attr('data-index')) {

  case 0:
    $('.skill_desc').html('<p>111</p>').css({'display':'block', 'text-align':'center', 'color':'white'});
    break;

  default:

}
event.preventDefault();
```

});

with above code I tried to render different DOM.

could anyone help me out why this code doesn't work? and would be happy to know if my approach is ever going to work.. !

Comment: `$('this')` probably should be `$(this)` - `'this'` is the literal string "this" which has no special meaning ... whereas in your code, `this` is the clicked element

Comment: also, you want `$('.skill_item')` - not `$('#skill_item')` ... `.` for classes, `#` for id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first mistake is that you are assigning `skill_item` class to your anchors, while in your jQuery code you are targeting anchor tags that has an ID of `skill_item` so instead `$('#skill_item')` use `$('.skill_item')`

The second mistake is here `$('this').attr('data-index');` it should be `$(this).attr('data-index');`

The third mistake is `$(this).attr('data-index');` returns the value as String. So either convert it to INT or in your case check for String value by putting case value into quotes.

Full working code.

```
$('.skill_item').click(function(event){
    var index = $(this).attr('data-index');
    switch (index) {
      case '0':
        $('.skill_desc').html('<p>111</p>').css({'display':'block', 'text-align':'center', 'color':'white'});
        break;
      default:
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Its always a good practice to cache values into a variable. For example `var index = $(this).attr('data-index');`

Comment: Since we're using jQuery, you could even shorten to `var index = $(this).data('index');`

Comment: Yes I agree! @ChrisForrence